# Handling missing data(only in single independent variable)

Tags: regression, missing-data

I was handling with data for regression problem, and proceeding pre-processing.

The data has about 6000 samples with 12 independent variables.

5 of them are factor and 7 of them are numeric variable.

However, one numeric variable that seems to be very linear(except weird outliers), but there's about 4000 missing values.

In this case, do I need to impute missing values or just remove those samples?

All other 11 variables do not have any missing.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: *Why* are these values missing?  If their missingness might be associated with the response variable, you will need to take great care.

Comment: Assuming that the plot shows this variable as x against your response y, also try to understand what the "outliers" mean. They may have a problematic influence on your regression (you may want to use robust regression anyway). Removing 4000 out of 6000 samples because missings in just one variable seems like a big waste. I don't know the meaning (and potential interactions with other variables!) of course, but in some such situations (depending on meaning and what goes on in the other variables) I'd consider dropping the x-variable instead.

Comment: @whuber There's not much explanation about the dataset, so I cannot find out the reason they are missing. But as I know about variable `x` and `y`, I'm sure missingness are not associated with the dependent variable. Thanks for your reply. Have a nice day :D.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I did look up correlations of numeric variables, and that `x` variable did have high correlation with two other independent variable(those are also highly correlated) and dependent variable `y`. Thanks for your idea, it make much better sense to remove `x` variable. Have a nice day :),

Comment: Re "not much explanation:" It is difficult to perform an adequate statistical analysis when you don't know what the data mean!  Perhaps a better course of action, then, would be to find out more about these data.